# How do I link SDL with Visual Studio 2019

Tags: sdl

I don't know how to link libraries with Visual Studio 2019 (I am using Windows 10), how do I link libraries?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 12):

It is the same as in VS 2017 and VS 2022.

> Project / "your project name" Properties... /

At **Configuration:** select **All Configurations**

Then

> Project / "your project name" Properties... / Configuration Properties / VC++ Directories /

At **Include Directories** add path to your SDL **include** folder
At **Library Directories** add path to your SDL lib folder ( **lib/x86** or **lib/x64** depending the active solution platform you selected in "your project name" Properties / Configuration Manager... )

Then

> Project / "your project name" Properties... / Configuration Properties
> / Linker / Input /

At **Additional Dependencies** add ( in this order ):
SDL2.lib
SDL2main.lib

Then copy all the **.dll** files from "your SDL folder" / lib / ( x86 or x64 )
to your Visual Studio solution **debug folder** ( the debug folder in the location where your .sln file is ).
In case you have solution and project in the same folder, then copy the files directly to your solution/project folder ( the folder where your .sln file is ).

Don't forget to use `#include <SDL.h>` in your code.
Also change `int main()` function in main.cpp with `int main(int argc, char* args[])`.

Comment: You can also use `int main()` but then you need to write `undef main` after `#include<SDL.h>`, that will work too.